# Difference between render and re-render in react?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, render

Whats the difference between render and re-render in react?
it must be a very noob question, sorry I am new in react.
thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between *render* and *re-render* is the same as between *execute* and *re-execute*.

*Execution* must occur first, before *re-execution* can happen.

> If something hadn't *rendered*, it can't *re-render*.

*Render* happens once, at first. *Re-render* can happen only after *render*, `nth` times.

Answer (score 1):

Render refers to rendering the content for the initial load.
Re-render refers to re-rendering the content upon updating of props.

You should learn the basics from https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html.

Welcome to Reactjs.